# grammatically, rotate + er is it correct?

Tags: grammar, terminology, programming, context

I try to name something as its usage is rotate+er.
The main usage is doing a rotation on a reliable circle, so I pick rotation as the verb.
My main lang is Indonesian, but I always try to give my best when it comes to writing in english.
The easiest name is changer but it's too broad, and losing the context it 'doing' on a reliable circle. So what is rotate + er, grammatically?
additional q:

- what is the term for verb + er = a concrete thing?

> link to ap.wa.hp.rotate.er

Comment: It's pretty universally "rotator", with an "o" -- a thing which rotates or which causes something to rotate.

Comment: It could also be a "rotor". The problem is that there are a lot of names for something that rotates: we need a sentence and some context. Could you do that?

Comment: The suffixes of English words derived from Latin often depend on vestiges of Latin grammar.

Comment: There is little point in discussing whether it should be a *rotator*, a *rotater*, or a *rotor*, for as long as a *changer* is exactly none of these things. What part exactly are you trying to label. What is the machinery in question, and what task does that particular bit perform within it. It does not matter whether it's *grammatically* correct to call it a purple cat, if that's not the actual technical term for it. Purple cat is perfectly fine. But absolutely nobody at all will understand what you're even on about.

Comment: To answer the question, the suffix _-er_ (or _-or_; English spelling is awful) is called an _agentive_ suffix. It can refer to a person (_actor, truck driver, buyer_) or to a thing (_cutter, screwdriver, cupholder_); you can't predict which.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **rotor** is *part of a machine* that rotates or is rotated *by* the machine.

A **rotator** is *a machine* that causes something else to rotate.

Comment: A rotator can be anything that rotates, machine or not. In each shoulder, humans have four muscles called _rotator cuffs_ which move the upper arm around. **Literally** around, since the shoulder is not a socket joint and the arm can rotate.

Comment: @John Lawler  - Thanks for the information.